# How to track content changes of a specific folder

Tags: c#

**Here is my scenario:**
Customer blames that a specific type of file will appear in a specific folder, when saving some files with our system. Our system works together with another system, not developed by us. I want to find out which system ist creating such files.

**This is what makes it more difficult:**
I suppose that those files appear temporarily. So in my small development scenario, it is nearly not possible to recognize them. But when working with many thousands of files, I suppose, the amount of temporary files will increase. And, due to the limits of customers hardware, they will exist much longer.

**So what I am looking for is a tool** which traces all changes of content in a specific folder. Ideally, I could filter for a specific type of file. It should work on Win10.

**My questions:**

- Does anybody know such a tool or could give me a suitable keywork for
  searching?
- Or is this too specific, so I have to make my own tool?

In the 2nd case I usually prefer C#/.NET. Is there anything suitable available, which I can extend or change or should use?   (e.g. a tool or framework or NuGet, e.g. extending a tool such as *Everything*)

Comment: Use the free Sysinternals _[Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace `System.IO` has a class that allows file and folder monitoring: `FileSystemWatcher`.

From the documentation:

> Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when
> a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0.

The documentation above gives a good code example, as well as many explanations about how changes are tracked, and eventual limitations.

You can use this class to log each change in a target folder, and then use this log to understand what happens.

If needed, you could then narrow down the issue using a tool like [SysInternal's ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). Assuming you gathered enough informations to be able to reproduce the problem, or be able to predict roughly when it could happen again, you could use *ProcessMonitor* to record system events.

*ProcessMonitor* records system events, via its *Capture* button. You can filter the events with the provided *Filter* mechanism. For instance (this is a simple case) you can filter to see only events from a specific *PID* (Process ID). You can find the *PID* of your target by looking at the details page of the *Task Manager*. This way you will likely find which process created which file.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, MickyD and Laurent Gabiot! ProcessMonitor has been my choice.